# All Stack Exchange site logos are showing up as the 3D Printing one

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logo

This just started happening on non-meta sites:

[image: MSE replaced with 3D]

Meta Stack Exchange's logo in the "Featured on Meta" section seems to have been replaced with some site's logo. Mousing over the icon does produce "Meta Stack Exchange" as normal, and the link works.

It even happens in the reputation and inbox dropdowns no matter what site they're visited on:

[image]

All the HNQs are showing as being from 3D Printing now:

[image]

Comment: @randal'thor It does indeed.

Comment: WTF. ***All*** the notifications in my inbox menu are now coming up as from 3D Printing: not just the MSE ones but from all sites!

Comment: It's an issue with the CSS class generation after some directory changes - we'll be pushing out a fix ASAP.

Comment: It also shows in the Inbox tab as well as all of the "Hot Network Questions" on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Great Scott, it's spreading! At first it wasn't in HNQ, now it is!

Comment: At least the *links* are still pointing to the correct place...

Comment: The issue appears to be with [the sprite sheet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=9fd5914646bc) where `3D` is at the top. It seems there's a network-wide failure to offset the sheet to show the correct icon.

Comment: Beat me to it! It's everywhere!

Comment: [Now it's just getting ridiculous...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cYKBt.png)

Comment: The hot network questions are the same icons as well

Comment: [I seem to have earned a lot of rep on 3D Printing today.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FRGJw.png)

Comment: For that matter, why is A51 the only site with a working logo?

Comment: It seems SE is 3D-printing all of us.

Comment: @IͶΔ It's clearly a conspiracy by 3D Printing to drive traffic to their site :P

Comment: perhaps 3D printers have become conscious of himself

Comment: @OldBunny2800, Area51 is somewhat separate from the rest of the network

Comment: There's a spy in the Stack Exchange dev team who was hired by the 3D Printing community to do this, no doubt!

Comment: Malkovich Malkovich?

Comment: Hahaha I reported the same just now xD.

Comment: "It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault." We have broken MSO.

Comment: @NickCraver Making a quick fix on a holiday − what could possibly go wrong with that? :D

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The build mitigation in place we had (to not remove the old files) didn't stick correctly in the production build, and a robocopy mirror wiped them out - a fix to the pathing is rolling out now. I'm building out now to resolve the favicons and /jobs issues - we're taking a look at the chat issue as well.

Comment: seems 3D printing became dominant and won over all other sites! (just kidding)

Comment: And the icons are back! (Not yet on chat, though)

Comment: For the curious: 3d printing is the first icon in the spritemap and with no classes to change the background position: it took over the joint.

Comment: 3D printers are trying to say something.. and that's only the beginning.

Comment: MSO is broken.  Clicking on any question now leads to "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

Comment: Super User is broken too.

Comment: Too aggressive a fix? No question is reachable, at least on TeX.SE and Math.SE

Comment: 17 hours later, still [not fixed for Careers/Jobs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277584/all-things-3d-so-careers-bug).

Comment: @ShadowWizard A fix was just pushed, it should be ok now

Comment: And [one more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277954/site-switcher-favicon-broken-across-all-blogs), this time with blogs. /cc @Aurélien