# What happened to SE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, homepage

Screenshot bug:

<kbd>[image: Screenshot bug]</kbd>

Why is the CSS broken like this? I visited [the homepage](http://stackexchange.com) and got the above image. What's wrong?

Comment: Probably [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/meta-stack-exchanges-logo-shows-up-as-3d)

Comment: Probably right. #CSSFAIL

Comment: Various sstatic.net urls are 404ing (e.g., http://sstatic.net/Sites/stackexchange/all.css ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fallout from site setting changes to the *rest* of the network. StackExchange.com is special and I reverted the setting changes there as soon as we realized it was broken.