# All things 3D - SO Careers bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was going through an [SO careers profile](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/thoma), where I found a bug. The favicon of all the SO accounts is that of 3D printing SO site.

> [image]

In addition to the accounts tab, the *top answers* tab also shows the same favicon:

> [image]

Is this a bug, or some cache problem in my PC?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know - this wasn't fixed in the Careers codebase before, it is now (thanks to Nick Craver)!

Comment: @Oded Yeah, fixed!  Awesome. Thanks :)  For a while, I thought the 3D site is taking over SO :D