# Site switcher favicon broken across all blogs

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, blog

I was on the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/) and saw this:

[image]

This is broken on every [Stack Exchange site blog](https://stackexchange.com/blogs) in existence except for [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) which is special and gets a different blog design.

Comment: My broken icon image is different but yes, I see the same issue.

Comment: @Catija It depends on the browser you're using. For example Firefox shows it as **[this](https://i.imgur.com/zZmAJLp.png)**.

Comment: Yep. That's what I see. I figured it was something like that.

Comment: +1 duplicated on Windows with latest Firefox

Comment: Looks like a remnant (hopefully the last :)) of [this major bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like these were not updated when we moved the content folder around.

Image paths adjusted and all is well in the blogoverflow site switcher.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Beginning to suspect this is a conspiracy to earn tons of Meta rep... ;)

Comment: I didn't make the change. Actually, I didn't fix the issue either. I'm just reporting things...

Comment: [Still not 100% fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278056/site-switcher-favicon-incorrect-on-some-blogs)