# Site switcher favicon incorrect on some blogs

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, blog, favicon

After the [issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277954/site-switcher-favicon-broken-across-all-blogs) of broken favicons on the site switcher was fixed, I noticed the [**Super User blog**](http://blog.superuser.com/) had **incorrect** site switcher favicons:

> [image]

It's the Stack Exchange favicon, not the Super User and Super User meta favicons.

I checked *all* other blogs, and the only other one that has this issue is the **[Ask Different blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/)**.

> [image]

Comment: It seems to be working right now. If you still have problems, you should try to clear your cache.

Comment: @Paweł Okay, well, I replicated this on another computer on a fresh browser when I made the question. If it's fixed now then great, though.