# All Stack Exchange site logos are showing up as the 3D Printing one REDUX

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, logo

[All Stack Exchange site logos are showing up as the 3D Printing one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one)

This bug just started showing up for me again; I noticed it on both computer and phone.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I actually managed to screw this up in a new and exciting way as we moved favicon generation around. Due to caching on dev, we missed it. It was a grep for `favicon.less`, but turns out our base `.less` includes it via: `@import "favicons/favicons"`, which didn't show up in my grep of "places to fix".

A fix is building out now.

Comment: It's always caching.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: https://isitchristmas.com/

Comment: it's back on working :)

Comment: Would this happen to be part of [that exciting deploy](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/806134797114413056)?

Comment: @Undo nope, this was actually a followup for Enterprise - that deploy went crazy smooth.

Answer (score 16):

I think it's unfair that 3D Printing gets to stamp their icon all over everyone else's stuff, and no one else does.

I vote that Stack Exchange should create a phantom site called `1 Stack Exchange`, which exists only on favicon lists, and which randomly selects an SE site every week to have as its favicon. That way if the favicon / HNQ symbol / top-bar chooser code bugs out, it's some lucky site's turn to get some free advertising. Plus, during December, you can set it to a Christmas tree - you know, for the holiday spirit.

---

No, seriously, though: good job on the stupendously fast fix on this one.