# My notifications etc are all 3D on some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon, activity-dropdown

This is odd:

[image] [image]

Comment: Duplicate: [All Stack Exchange site logos are showing up as the 3D Printing one REDUX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287844/228367)